# send an asset with private key (colored coins, Colu SDK)

Tags: private-key, bitcoin, blockchain, bitcoin-testnet

In accordance with Colored Coins documentation I have sent an asset on `testnet` like this:

```
var issuance_address = 'n2t19a46cBs2DdHs2sqfRwPGhoQjvqmefR';
var key = bitcoin.ECKey.makeRandom();
var wif = key.toWIF();
var to_address = key.pub.getAddress(bitcoin.networks.testnet).toString();
// to_address = 'mhLbuNgefJer5HFpq1UeW2PTq9RyttwghL'
console.log('new TESTNET address: ['+to_address+']');

var send_asset = {
    'from': [issuance_address],
    'to': [{
        'address': to_address,
        'amount': 5,
        'assetId': 'LKXjG9uMSFoDj2Z6NrEJ6nkcRGVtjUmC4zrtH'
    }]
};

colu.sendAsset(send_asset, function (err, body) {
        if (err){
            return console.error(err);
        }
        console.log('success',body);
}
```

And it works properly. But how can I transfer coins back from `to_address` to `issuance_address`?

I suppose it is possible with generated `WIF` private key for `to_address`

```
wif = 'Kyn7ihNLyTXKjWBAD99AY3LDJL4DeLapt4wWwFa4MMjirZe2QbEf'
```

What the code should be then for this purpose?

If I just replace the `issuance_address` with `to_address` it throws error:

```
Addresss mhLbuNgefJer5HFpq1UeW2PTq9RyttwghL privateKey not found
```

How to use given private key (WIF?) for such transfer? I found nothing about this in documentation from both Colored Coins and Colu SDK.

Comment: is this the whole code? i am not seeing the colu.init()

Answer (score 0):

This error becoz u try to send to address that have different PrivateSeed or PrivateKey.

From Colu SDK document

> since obviously we shouldn't be able to issue an asset on an address
>   that we don't control.